# Overloading by return type?

Tags: c#, .net, syntax-error

```
public class test
{
    public void xov() { return; }
    public string xov() { return null; }
    public int xov() { return 0; } 
}

public class p
{
    public p()
    {
        test v = new test();
        v.xov();// Here i cann't use defined overloads :(  
    }   
}
```

I can overload methods by parameters , but why cann't I overload methods by return type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The return type is not considered part of a method's signature. That is, methods cannot be overloaded if they differ only by return type.

Answer (score 2):

Calling

```
int x =  Add(5,6);
```

might be diffrent than:

```
string y = Add(5,6);
```

But what if no one reads the return type?

```
Add(5,6);
```

How is the compiler suppose to know which add was called?
So this option is not legal.

Answer (score 1):

> A return type of a method is not part of the signature of the method
>   for the purposes of method overloading. However, it is part of the
>   signature of the method when determining the compatibility between a
>   delegate and the method that it points to.

[Link to MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173114.aspx)